# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function ... does not exist

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

I am trying to execute a function which comes from an extension (`postgis`) with `psycopg2`.

```
import psycopg2

AFRICA = "africa"
ANTARCTICA = "antarctica"
ASIA = "asia"
AUSTRALIA_OCEANIA = "australia-oceania"
CENTRAL_AMERICA = "central-america"
EUROPE = "europe"
NORTH_AMERICA = "north-america"
SOUTH_AMERICA = "south-america"

SCHEMAS = [AFRICA, ANTARCTICA, ASIA, AUSTRALIA_OCEANIA,
           CENTRAL_AMERICA, EUROPE, NORTH_AMERICA, SOUTH_AMERICA]

def createCentroidTableFromPolygon(fromTable, toTable):
    return f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {toTable} AS
        SELECT public.ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom, way_id, osm_type, name FROM {fromTable};
    """

for schema in SCHEMAS:    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host='localhost',
        database='world',
        user="postgres",
        password="postgres",
        port=5432,
        options=f"-c search_path={schema}"
    )

    for i, table in enumerate(TABLES):
        with conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                # this works!
                cursor.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM {table} LIMIT 10""")
                print(cursor.fetchall())

                # this throws an error
                cursor.execute(createCentroidTableFromPolygon(
                table, FROM_POLY_TABLES[i]))
```

This gives me

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function public.st_centroid(public.geometry) does not exist
> LINE 3:     SELECT public.ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom, way_id, osm_type, name...
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

The extension `postgis` is installe on the `database world` though.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
```

[image: extensions postgres]

I tried already this

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
```

and checking the privileges

```
SELECT DISTINCT privilege_type FROM information_schema.usage_privileges ;
```

which returned only

> privilege_type : USAGE

When I try to run the postgis function in `pgAdmin`, it works without a problem... So there seems to be a Python - Postgres/PostGIS problem. But what might be the problem?

Comment: Your code runs fine, though you don't show definition of TABLES and FROM_POLY_TABLES. Tested with python 3.10.6 and psycopg2 2.9.4.

Comment: @PepeNO On my old machine it run fine as well. Since switching to a new one, I am having trouble running it.

Comment: Debug your code, put the code block of your second for in a `try: ... except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(cursor.query) 
        print("\n")   
        print(error)
    finally:
        conn.close() ` to see how your query is formed when execution fails.

Comment: @PepeNO sorry for the late reply. I am getting the same error message... As I wrote. Before switching from my old machine to a newer one, this code run without a problem too. This user is having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520114/executing-postgresql-function-from-python. There is solution on gis.stackexchange to this problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324386/psycopg2-programmingerror-function-does-not-exist which seems to be the exact same problem... But, it is not solving here. To me it feels like a permission thing, because this probable changed

Comment: mvoing from my old machine to my new machine. The new OS X is way more stricter with permissions than the old one.

Comment: If this problem has no answer here, it would be useful to answer your own question.

Comment: @PepeNO If I ever find the solution to this, I will... But I am running against a wall here :/